# Java and static member/function access without object

Tags: java, static, java.util.scanner

I am brand new to Java from a little of C++ and I am wondering what happens when I call a static method or access a static field without having an instance of the class:

```
class Foo {
    public final static Scanner _input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

class Bar {
    public final static Scanner _input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

...

SomeCode[Foo._input.nextInt()];
```

I can't imagine a temp object is created, but have no idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering what happens when I call a static method or access a static field without having an instance of the class

It just accesses the field... it's as simple as that. It *doesn't* create an instance of `Foo` - it wouldn't need to.

The field isn't associated with any instance of the type - it's associated with the type itself. That's what `static` means in Java, basically. You should try to ignore any of the meanings of `static` in C++ which are somewhat different, I'm afraid.

One thing to be aware of is effectively a problem in the design of Java - you *can* access static members via references, but it doesn't mean what you'd expect. For example:

```
Foo foo = null;
Scanner scanner = foo._input;
```

That *looks* like it will go bang with a `NullPointerException` - but it doesn't. That code is equivalent to:

```
Foo foo = null;
Scanner scanner = Foo._input;
```

It's worth avoiding the first form of code as far as possible. It can be really misleading, particularly when you're calling methods - it *looks* like the call relies on the instance (and can be polymorphic) but actually both of those are incorrect :(

Answer (score 1):

**temp object is created???**

> static keyword to create fields and methods that belong to the class, rather than to an instance of the class.

[Heavily recommending](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

`static` fields are associated with the class itself. Their resolution is done at compile time; initialization of static variables (and static initialization blocks) are run when the class is loaded by the JVM.

As to how to access such variables (or methods), you can either use the class name, as you do; but Java also allows you to do that using instance variables of the class. Including `null` ones!

All these three expressions allow to access a static variable named `bar` in class `Foo` (**provided that `bar` is visible by the caller**):

```
Foo.bar;            // using the class name
new Foo().bar;      // using an instance
((Foo) null).bar;   // using a null instance
```

Comment: "static instance variables" is a contradiction in terms. You mean just "static fields" - the point is that they're *not* associated with an instance.

Comment: Oops, yes, sorry... Fixed.

Comment: And no, those three lines *aren't* equivalent - the second one creates an instance of `Foo` but the others don't.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't imagine a temp object is created,

Nope.  You use the class object to call the method.

Comment: "class object" is not clear. I think instance of class Class is better

Answer (score 1):

You have used both static and final keyword , Both have different meaning.

When you declare any variable using static keyword then its declared as a class variable ,Means its common to all instance of that class. access using class name no need to use instance .

E.g.

```
Class Bycicle
{
   static String Type ='exercise';
    String Owner;

}
```

If you create 10 instance of this class then 1o copy of owner will created , while type will remain only one common copy for all 10 object.  One object change type value then it will effect to all other object.

if you are declaring static with final then it common to all and also not allowed to change once it declared and initialize at compile time.

Go here for more interesting details [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)